# "'Context' object has no attribute 'active_object'" error when trying to use function as driver

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

```
import bpy

def driver_func(val):
    activeobj = bpy.context.active_object

    if activeobj.name == "A":
        output = val * val
    else:
        output = val + 20

    return output

#add function to driver_namespace
bpy.app.driver_namespace['driver_func'] = driver_func
```

Thanks to RJG for the improvement.
This script indeed runs in the scripting editor without errors, but when I
add `driver_func` in the driver's editor as scripted expression to an object's transform (e.g. z-rotation) I get ERROR: Invalid Python Expression ...

The terminal message reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<bpy driver>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/Users/.../Test.blend/TestPython", line 4, in driver_func
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'active_object'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could enable *Use Self* in the driver editor to get access to the object that the driver is used on. Then you would need to modify the arguments passed into function and use `self` to check for the name instead of trying to get the active object. The modified script look like this:

```
import bpy

def driver_func(self, val):
    if self.name == "A":
        output = val * val
    else:
        output = val + 20

    return output

#add function to driver_namespace
bpy.app.driver_namespace['driver_func'] = driver_func
```

Modify the expression to `driver_func(self, var)` or replace `var` with whatever your variable is called. Be aware that your current script increases the value *very* quickly.

[image: Driver settings]

I'm not an expert at Blender's drivers, so if somebody more experienced has a better solution, feel free to add another answer.

---

Alternatively you can access the active object through `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active` as you've pointed out in the comments. Then the script would look like this:

```
import bpy

def driver_func(val):
    active_obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active

    if active_obj.name == "A":
        output = val * val
    else:
        output = val + 20

    return output

#add function to driver_namespace
bpy.app.driver_namespace['driver_func'] = driver_func
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I don't want to access the object the driver is used on. The object with the driver is controlled by parameters of other objects via the function. I found a different solution, if one changes the syntax to  _activeobj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active_ it works.